# How can I add Drift JavaScript to a readthedocs site?

Tags: javascript, read-the-docs, drift

This is the site [Aviatrix](http://docs.aviatrix.com) and these are the [instructions from Drift](https://help.drift.com/installing-drift/install-drift-on-your-website-javascript).
And this is what the [*readthedocs* help says](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html).

However I've tried these and it won't appear on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already figured this out but I just went through this same process and I figured out a way to do it. Here's how.

I added the drift install script in a drift.js file and put that under docs/jsfiles/

Then all I had to do was add this to my yml: 
extra_javascript: ['jsfiles/drift.js']

And that worked! I think this processes the js script at the end of the page load but I'm sure there's a way to move the script to the head tag of each page as well. Will report on it when I figure it out. For now, I'm going to go with this solution.